# Why Javascript's extend function has to set Object's prototype's constructor properly?

Tags: javascript

This is the definition of `extend` in Pro Javascript Design Patterns, Apress, 2008, p.44:

```
function extend(subClass, superClass) {
  var F = function() {};
  F.prototype = superClass.prototype;
  subClass.prototype = new F();
  subClass.prototype.constructor = subClass;

  subClass.superclass = superClass.prototype;
  if(superClass.prototype.constructor == Object.prototype.constructor) {
    superClass.prototype.constructor = superClass;
  }
}
```

For the line `subClass.superclass = superClass.prototype;`, I think it probably is equally the same if we do `subClass.superclass = superClass`, since in the future, we can always get to the prototype by `subClass.superclass.prototype` anyway.  But I thought why not point to the constructor function, but point to the prototype?  But this is a minor question.

The more important questions is, why do the last lines try to set the Object's prototype's constructor back to self?  I tried it in Firefox and Chrome, and they always point that way already.

Also a little strange is that, why does it use `if(superClass.prototype.constructor == Object.prototype.constructor)` ?  Why not just use `if (superClass === Object)` instead?

Comment: The constructor property is what makes instanceof work. It's a fine detail that honestly doesn't often matter.

Comment: @MattGreer: Wrong. The `constructor` property has no functional purpose in EcmaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `subClass.superclass = superClass.prototype;`
>   Why not point to the constructor function, but point to the prototype?

Both could be done, and it's just a design issue. I guess that `superClass` property is mostly needed in overwritten methods that want to call their super method, and they can do so by calling `this.constructor.superClass[methodName]`. But yes, it is a bit weird that you need the `constructor` property for this, a direct property on the prototype would have been easier again.

> The more important questions is, why do the last lines try to set the Object's prototype's constructor back to self?

It seems that is done for compatibility with poor prototype declarations. If someone uses

```
MyClass.prototype = {…};
```

and does not reset the `constructor`, then in `extend(MySubClass, MyClass)` the `superClass.prototype.constructor` will be `Object`, and the common applying of the superclass constructor

```
this.constructor.superClass.constructor.apply(this, args);
// for those who don't want to use MyClass.apply
```

in the `MySubClass` constructor would fail. So the `extend` function corrects this.

> Also a little strange is that, why does it use `if(superClass.prototype.constructor == Object.prototype.constructor)`? Why not just use `if (superClass === Object)` instead?

It should be clear now why we want `superClass.prototype.constructor`. But yes, we could have used `Object` instead of `Object.prototype.constructor`.